# Averaging the averages with weights

Tags: applications

An international company has offices in different countries. The company wants to look at the office expenditures on stationery across it's offices.

Because sourcing locations are different, similar list of items costed differently.

```
8 offices in Europe spent on average $200
8 offices in America spent on average $300
5 offices in Asia spent on average $100
```

What would be the one representative number to reflect the spending overall?

Thinking to use the number of office and their averaged spends, sum them up and divide by the total number of offices, i.e.

```
(8 * 200 + 8 * 300 + 5 *100) / (8+8+5) = $214 (rounded)
```

It doesn't seem good as not considering the contributions of European and Asian offices.

If it uses the medium of [100,200,300], i.e. 200. It is neither fair.

In this way, it still returns $214 (rounded):

[image]

What would be the good way to consider the number of different offices and their contributions?

Comment: Your first calculation (the one that yielded \$300) is incorrect. That formula is equivalent to what you did and actually yields \$214 (after rounding).

Comment: @prubin, thank you for pointing out the mistake, sir! I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your weighting based approach looks probably OK,
but given that there are different categories such as Europe vs Asia, and there may be additional factors such as office size, you might want to check if Simpson's Paradox might occur:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox

Comment: thanks for the help!